# Restart Activity Android

Tags: android, andengine, restart

I'm working on an Android application that uses AndEngine. I try to restart an activity in this way:

```
private void restartActivity() {
    startActivity(new Intent(this, TMXTiledMapExample.class));
    finish();
}
```

This solution works on most devices, but I've realized that not the Nexus4.

In fact, I get the following error :

```
08-06 11:24:17.416: E/AndroidRuntime(6299): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-06 11:24:17.416: E/AndroidRuntime(6299): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-06 11:24:17.416: E/AndroidRuntime(6299):     at org.andengine.ui.activity.BaseGameActivity.onResumeGame(BaseGameActivity.java:222)
08-06 11:24:17.416: E/AndroidRuntime(6299):     at org.andengine.ui.activity.BaseGameActivity$4.run(BaseGameActivity.java:373)
08-06 11:24:17.416: E/AndroidRuntime(6299):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
08-06 11:24:17.416: E/AndroidRuntime(6299):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-06 11:24:17.416: E/AndroidRuntime(6299):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-06 11:24:17.416: E/AndroidRuntime(6299):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
08-06 11:24:17.416: E/AndroidRuntime(6299):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-06 11:24:17.416: E/AndroidRuntime(6299):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
08-06 11:24:17.416: E/AndroidRuntime(6299):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
08-06 11:24:17.416: E/AndroidRuntime(6299):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
08-06 11:24:17.416: E/AndroidRuntime(6299):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to restart activity like this:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
finish();
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: It works great. One explanation may be? Why on other devices, but not on this one?

Comment: Honestly I have no idea, one thing I noticed while working is that google phones in general seem a little bit off (especially nexus 4). Glad it works tho

Answer (score 0):

if like this u're close new activity

> startActivity(new Intent(this, TMXTiledMapExample.class));
>     finish();

just change finish() first

> finish();
>   startActivity(new Intent(this, TMXTiledMapExample.class));